# SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-material, angular5

I'm trying to up & run legacy web app. I have installed all packages and repaired broken packages.json file. Now app compiles well with no issues.

[image]

When I load app in browser I see console error says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Any idea where to look for error / issue? All compiles well with no issues.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your console?

Comment: Is there not a filename and line number next to the error message in the console windows? Clicking on that should take you to the offending location.

Comment: That looks like a JSON post-build issue. Most likely, you're making an HTTP call and trying to convert the response to JSON, but the bracket is not supposed to be there. Do you have an error stack anyway ?

Comment: Guys, just updated my question with console error screenshot

Comment: error is in your `app.js` please add that file.

Comment: I don't have app.js file. It think it gets compiled from TS files / components / modules

Comment: click on the error link which is showing `app.js:15` in your image It ll redirect to your error.

Comment: yeah, it shows me this webpack code - http://prntscr.com/j6f6p0. But I don't know how to understand what's wrong from this line..

Comment: check for any syntax error in `webpack.js` file

Comment: Sorry, how I can do it @Sravan?

Comment: Please check you `<base href="/">` in `index.html` and also what's being generated/rendered in the browser via console.

Comment: Try building for AOT: `ng build --aot`. It may reveal more errors.